# Conflicting between Firebase messaging and Content Provider when i use them together

Tags: android, firebase

I have an application that share locations between users on Google maps and sorting and retrieving database using content provider and also opening chat messages using firebase messaging but when i combine  Firebase messaging and Android content provider together the conflict happens and i found the error below , although when i use content provider or firebase messaging separately they work well and i have outputs from both, but once i combine both i have that message :

```
04-22 09:13:36.734 23186-23186/pioneers.safwat.onecommunity E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/pioneers.safwat.onecommunity-5.apk
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5199)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4802)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4686)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:168)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1389)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5496)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path: /data/app/pioneers.safwat.onecommunity-5.apk
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5184)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4802) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4686) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1389) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:177) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5496) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1225) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1041) 
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my Gradle file is (Module) :

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pioneers.safwat.onecommunity"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
     compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
    // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1'
  // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
   compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my gradle file( Build):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="pioneers.safwat.onecommunity">
    <permission
        android:name="pioneers.safwat.onecommunity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="pioneers.safwat.onecommunity.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".Start">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Authentic"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
        <activity android:name=".UserData"/>
        <activity android:name=".UpdateData"/>
        <provider
            android:name=".Myprovider"
            android:authorities="pioneers.safwat.onecommunity.Myprovider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: remove maps and location gradle lines. only use compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in your manifest

```
<application
   ....
  android:name=".MyApplication">

 // ...
</application>
```

Then make a class.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

Try this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html) for more details.